# Is getchar() gets a character from input?

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

code:

```
while(  (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
    putchar( c );
}
```

when I input `abc`

I guess the output is 
`aabbcc`
, but the output is

```
abc
abc
```

why ?

Comment: It uses buffered streams. For example, you can delete characters using the Backspace key until you press the enter key.

Comment: `putchar()`, among other I/O functions, is buffered. The output doesn't appear until the output is flushed. And since your program doesn't call `flush()` or call an input function after `putchar()`, I assume that it occurs only when your program ends.